# How do I become a multimedia programmer?

Tags: multimedia

Recently I'm interesting in multimedia programming but all I know about multimedia is simple and basic concepts related to codecs and container formats. So can you tell me from where to begin and is there some good books which explain multimedia concepts from software programming   standpoint. In fact, I'm looking for the prerequisite knowledges and key concepts of multimedia programming which a software developer must master

Comment: Multimedia programmer sounds like someone developing interactive CD-ROMs in the 90s

Comment: @Alexandre Hilarious and true.

Comment: You want http://careeroverflow.com, not here.

Comment: Haha, even CD-ROMs sounds 90s

Comment: @Blaenk I'm listening to Beth Orton on one at the moment.

Comment: maybe there should be an overflowoverlflow.com to tell us which website is most appropriate for a particular question

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin And now, in 2014, it is really classy! :))

Answer (score 3):

If you have a little mathematical background, you should learn something about **DSP** (Digital Signal Processing), there are lots of books and websites Eg: http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm

And in that area it's quite popular Matlab (there are free clones, as [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)) , its high level language well suited to experiment with DSP and grasp the main concepts.